# 7zip compress batch for subfolders in Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, 7zip, subdirectory

I have a folder with subfolders that contain folders named "Images". I want to compress all those Images folders with 7zip and store it as 7s archieve to each original folder aside. So far I wrote a .bat and in seemed to work... but surprise surprise, all the archieves created are EMPTY. Could annyone tell why and how to fix this? The .bat is opend in the top folder which contains all the subfolders.

```
@Echo off
   call:myCompressFunction
   goto :eof

:myCompressFunction
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (

IF  "%%G" == "Images" (
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ^
a ^
"%%G.7z" ^
"%%G\" ^
-m0=BZip2 ^
-mx=9)

cd %%G\
call:myCompressFunction
cd..
)
exit /b
```

When I paste the code for one folder in the cmd I opend there, it works:

```
for /d %G in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"  a "%G.7z" "%G\" -m0=BZip2 -mx=9
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the fault. There should be no marks around %%G.7s and %%G\

Here is the full code of the .bat-file with some comments added:

```
REM Compresses all folders and subfolders in the folder it is opened but
REM The if-function restricts the folders to be compresses to those named in the if-condition
REM 7z-files are stored aside the original folder

@Echo off
call:myCompressFunction
goto :eof

REM function executed in all subfolders
:myCompressFunction
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (

REM compresses all folders named Images
IF  "%%G" == "Images" (
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ^
a ^
%%G.7z ^
%%G\ ^
-m0=BZip2 ^
-mx=9)

cd %%G\
call:myCompressFunction
cd..
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem are actually not the [quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43259077), but the fact that you do line continuation using `^`, which actually escapes the first character of the next line; so the code portion...:

```cmd
(
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ^
a ^
"%%G.7z" ^
"%%G\" ^
-m0=BZip2 ^
-mx=9)
```

...is actually read by the command interpreter as...:

```cmd
("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ^a ^"%G.7z" ^"%G\" ^-m0=BZip2 ^-mx=9)
```

...and this leads to some escaped quotation marks `^"`. Special characters like the the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and the caret `^` are not detected in case they appear within a pair of `""`. Therefore after having resolved the escaping and tokenising the command line, the following tokens are received:

```cmd
(                                  // the opening parenthesis is detected
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"    // a single token as the spaces are in between `""`
a                                  // `^a` becomes `a`
^"%G.7z" ^"%G\" ^-m0=BZip2 ^-mx=9) /* the first `^"` is just a literal character `"`
                                      without any function, opposed to a non-escaped `"`;
                                      the next `^` appears in between two functional `""`,
                                      hence it is kept; the fourth `"` is another opening
                                      one, so the rest of the line appears quoted, leading
                                      to the next `^`s being kept too and the `)` not to
                                      be recognised as the closing parenthesis, so there
                                      appears one `)` missing in the code */
```

If you precede every continued line with one or more <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, you are no longer escaping some functional characters unintentionally, but the first <kbd>SPACE</kbd>,...:

```cmd
(
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ^
  a ^
  "%%G.7z" ^
  "%%G\" ^
  -m0=BZip2 ^
  -mx=9)
```

...so it becomes interpreted as...:

```cmd
(  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ^  a ^  "%G.7z" ^  "%G\" ^  -m0=BZip2 ^  -mx=9)
```

...where the escaped <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> do not disturb, and so the line is tokenised into:

```cmd
(                                  // the opening parenthesis is detected
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"    // a single token as the spaces are in between `""`
a                                  // `a` is kept unaltered
"%G.7z"                            // this is a correctly quoted token
"%G\"                              // this too
-m0=BZip2                          // this is an unquoted token
-mx=9                              // and this too
)                                  /* the closing parenthesis is detected now properly,
                                      because it does no longer appear quoted */
```